# Right approach to replace ANT task with gradle custom task written in java and set the ant filesets on gradle tasks

Tags: java, gradle, ant, build.gradle

I am working on migrating one of our ANT and MAVEN java project into GRADLE.
I am able to migrate the build part and some smaller ant target with Gradle custom task. 
However we have some code written in java which extends org.apache.tools.ant.Task and it is called during runtime through ant using the build.xml. The build.xml has the typedef refering to the ant Task (eg: MyDataImportTask) which iterates through list of filesets (various files from some directory matching pattern) and then does some updates in the data base or something.
It has dependencies on libraries like hibernate, apache ant etc.

Now I am trying to write a custom task using gradle to rewrite that class and not able to find the right approach. I am stuck how to pass the filesets into that custom task. I have also tried using gradle SourceTask where we can set the sources objects but not working. Can someone help me please?

Second challenge is that currently this module is part of java project. I am trying to move it to buildSrc folder for the custom task that I am re-writing. I have a feeling that this is not the right approach. I am wondering how do I pass the source filesets to the compiled jar file and then call it from the custom GRADLE task. Can someone help me please?

Following is the example of class which extends the ant task and then it is used in the build.xml to execute it.

```
public class MyDataImportTask extends org.apache.tools.ant.Task{
    private String myPrefix;
    //getter setter

    private List<FileSet> filesets = new ArrayList<FileSet>();

    public void execute() throws BuildException{
        ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
        ((AntClassLoader) cl).setThreadContextLoader();

        try{

            for (int i = 0; i < filesets.size(); i++) {
                    FileSet fs = (FileSet) filesets.get(i);
                    DirectoryScanner ds = null;
                    try {
                        ds = fs.getDirectoryScanner(getProject());
                    } catch (BuildException e) {
                        getLogger().info("Warning: " + e.getMessage());
                        continue;
                    }

                    final File fromDir = fs.getDir(getProject());
                    final String[] srcFiles = ds.getIncludedFiles();

                    if (srcFiles != null) {
                        //Do something with srcFiles
                    }

            }
        }

        finally {
            ((AntClassLoader) cl).resetThreadContextLoader();
        }
    }
}
```

I have ANT build.xml with following code:

```
    <typedef name="mydataimport" classname="com.surendra.data.tasks.MyDataImportTask" classpathref="classpath"/>

    <mydataimport myPrefix="myData.">
        <fileset dir="${rootDir}/MyData/types">
            <include name="abc.xmi" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${rootDir}/MyData/types">
            <include name="*.xmi" />
            <exclude name="abc.xmi" />
        </fileset>
    </mydataimport>
```

I expect to have my custom task called in build.gradle as:

```
task myDataImportTask(type: MyDataImportTask){
    sources = "${rootDir}/MyData/types"
    patternToInclude1 ="*.xmi" 
    patternToExclude ="abc.xmi" 
}
```